# How to make the data in month drop-down-list to be (Jan,Feb,......,Dec)

Tags: symfony1

in the sfWidgetFormDateTime a 2 options (date,time).
and in my sfWidgetFormDateTime i add this option
this->addOption('date', array('format'=>'%day%/%month%/%year%')).

The data in the month DropDownList shows the month between (0-12), but i want the data in the month DropDownList to be show (Jan,....,Dec).

So, what the way to do it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following information on http://fabien.potencier.org/chapter_10.html

```
// Date
$form->setWidget('dob', new sfWidgetFormI18nDate(array(
  'culture'      => $this->getUser()->getCulture(),
  'month_format' => 'name',   // Use any of 'name' (default), 'short_name', and 'number' 
  'label'        => 'Date of birth',
  'default'      => '01/01/1950',
  'years'        => array(1950, 1951, .., 1990)
)));

// For an English-speaking user, symfony renders the widget in HTML as
<label for="dob">Date of birth</label>
<select id="dob_month" name="dob[month]">
  <option value=""/>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  ...
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select> /
<select id="dob_day" name="dob[day]">...</select> /
<select id="dob_year" name="dob[year]">...</select>

// For an French-speaking user, symfony renders the widget in HTML as
<label for="dob">Date of birth</label>
<select id="dob_day" name="dob[day]">...</select> /
<select id="dob_month" name="dob[month]">
  <option value=""/>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Janvier</option>
  <option value="2">Février</option>
  ...
  <option value="12">Décembre</option>
</select> /
<select id="dob_year" name="dob[year]">...</select>
```

Similar widgets exist for time (sfWidgetFormI18nTime), and datetime (sfWidgetFormI18nDateTime).